# setInterval(setTimeout) function for given invokes javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need to invoke some function given number of times through given delays. How should I do - declare variable for timer and pass it to invoking function for stopping timer in some moment or in loop (n times) invoke setTimeout once ( or some another approach to skeep delay time once) or other.Thanks.

**edit to fix syntax eror**

```
    var timerID = null;
    var n = 5;
    this.timerID = setInterval(function(){ 
              funcToInvoke(n,timerID){ 
                   if(invokeNumber == n){
                       clearInterval(timerID);
                       return;
                   }
                   else { do something}
               }
    },delay)
```

Comment: Yes, `setInterval` (or a "recursive" call to `setTimeout`) is better than a loop that invokes `setTimeout` several times.

Comment: does approach I show is common used (and right) ?

Comment: Your `funcToInvoke` is a syntax error (or parsed as an invocation + a code block, which is not what you want). Please fix it, and notice that the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the interval-function does not point to your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current method has a syntax problem, you can't have a function parameter like `this.timerID`). In fact, you should remove the whole `funcToInvoke` declaration, and declare `n` and `timerID` as local variables, so they will be available to the closure. Like this:

```
// Don't forget to define n here!
var n = 5;
// Change timerID to local var instead of property
var timerID = null;
timerID = setInterval(function(){ 
    if(invokeNumber == n){
        clearInterval(timerID);
        return;
    } else { 
        //do something
    }
    // You can setTimeout again anywhere in this function if needed
}, delay);
```

Comment: This still suffers the same problem. Either it is supposed to be a useless function declaration (which it is not), or a call to `funcToInvoke` plus a statement block.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that was an oversight `funcToInvoke` is unnecessary. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the approach is common and better than calling `setTimeout` in a loop (with a fixed number of times). It is more performant than that and also more flexible, because the interval will be stopped dynamically (might check for a future condition).

However, your code is a bit messy. Fixed:

```
// Assuming we a have
//  n
//  delay
//  funcToInvoke
// and execute in context of some object
var that = this,
    numberOfInvokes = 0;
this.timer = setInterval(function() {
     // "this" points to the global object
     if (numberOfInvokes == n)
          clearInterval(that.timer);
     else
          funcToInvoke(numberOfInvokes);
     numberOfInvokes++;
}, delay);
```

Comment: This is what my answer should have looked like if I'd been more careful then. +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an approximate delay, setInterval is probably ok. If you want a more precise interval, then repeated calls to setTimeout are better as you can adjust the length of time to the next call based on the time since the last call.

E.g. for a clock ticking every second, you can do repeated calls to setTimeout, setting the lag to just after the next full second.